# redirect to php page after ajax success in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

i am working on search form with autocomplete function. my autocomplete is working fine. i want to send the data to another php page after autocomplete value is set.
below is my jquery for autocompleate.

```
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#searchitem').val();
    var search_location = $('#search_location').val();
    var datastring= 'keyword='+ keyword + '&search_location='+search_location;
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'global_search.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datastring,
            success:function(data){
                $('#search_list_id').show();
                $('#search_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#search_list_id').hide();
    }
}
// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#searchitem').val(item);

      window.location.href = 'searchtestr.php?key=' + data
    // hide proposition list
    $('#search_list_id').hide();
}
```

i tried `window.location.href = 'searchtestr.php?key=' + data` to redirect the page but its not working. the condition is the page should be redirect after some thing is selected from autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `set_item` method in your `success` handler:

```
    success:function(data){
        $('#search_list_id').show();
        $('#search_list_id').html(data);
        set_item(data.item); //data.something
    }
```

Also, you are trying to pass a variable called `data` to the next page but the `set_item` method doesn't have access to that variable. You'd have to send `item` e.g. `window.location.href = 'searchtestr.php?key=' + item;`

Also, I'm not sure if you are doing something with a SPA (guessing not)... I don't think it makes sense to modify the DOM after you redirect the page - e.g. `$('#search_list_id').hide();` and `$('#searchitem').val(item);`. You are aware that`window.location.href` is not triggering an AJAX call and will redirect the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#searchitem').val();
    var search_location = $('#search_location').val();
    var datastring= 'keyword='+ keyword + '&search_location='+search_location;
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'global_search.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datastring,
            success:function(data){
                $('#search_list_id').show();
                $('#search_list_id').html(data);
            },
   change: function (event, ui) {
   if (ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined) {
  
   } else {
    window.location.href = 'searchtestr.php?key=' + data;
   }
        });
    } else {
        $('#search_list_id').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error ReferenceError: set_item is not defined

Answer (score -1):

i tried like below and it worked. my concern is after value is set then redirect to php page.

```
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#searchitem').val();
    var search_location = $('#search_location').val();
    var datastring= 'keyword='+ keyword + '&search_location='+search_location;
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'global_search.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datastring,
            success:function(data){
                $('#search_list_id').show();
                $('#search_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#search_list_id').hide();
    }
}
// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#searchitem').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#search_list_id').hide();

     var location = $('#search_location').val();
     var search_term = $('#searchitem').val();

     if(search_term != ''){
     window.location.href = 'searchtestr.php?location=' + location + '&search_term='+ search_term;
     }
}
```

Thank You all for helping me.